# Default Interactive TTY prints daemon output

Tags: systemd, rsyslog, systemd-journald, coreos

I work for a company that deploys clustered products using coreos and docker, and as part of our deployment, we automatically start up a few docker containers to expose, among others, a web interface for the client to interact with.

The issue I am facing at the moment is that the terminal (be it bare metal, vmware, virtualbox) where coreos is deployed (non-ssh) is very verbose.  It dumps all sorts of systemd information, as well as docker daemon output directly to the client-facing terminal.

I rebuilt the coreos ISO to include some auto-deployment stuff, and would prefer if there was a way I could turn off this verbosity at ISO level, or even soon after boot (by adding a script to the ISO).

I need to find out why this default terminal is used to dump daemon output?

Comment: Presumably this terminal gets chosen as the console, so any syslog config directing output to /dev/console will appear. Remove that config line. Boot messages will appear too. Try adding keyword `quiet` to the boot line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much googling, and some direction from a colleague, the solution was found to be:

Create file:

```
/etc/sysctl.d/kp.conf
```

with contents:

```
kernel.printk = 2 4 1 7
```

Default coreos kernel print parameters were 7 4 1 7.  The initial 7 made kernel print INFO level logging to terminal.  Now it will only print emergency stuff.